# What is the best way to animate the size of sub view in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've got a scrollview that allows the user to scroll between different pages and then tap on one to have it expand so that they can read the page in full, a little like how one changes tabs in Safari on the iPhone. Changing the frame size of each sub view is a bit of a pain when rotating as the scroll position is getting lost as the content size of the sub view has to change too. I was wondering if there was a more effective way of
resizing the views for entering 'viewing' mode or rotating the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your first problem is when you want to expand the view, pull it out of the scrollView then add it to self.view.subviews with an appropriate frame, then animate the frame to fill the screen. When done with it do the reverse, shrink it, then when its back to the appropriate size stick it back in the scrollView.

If for some reason this does not work - the scrollview is showing other stuff that gets moved when you remove the view, then instead of just removing your view from it, create a simple UIView of the same size as the view you will expand, and essentially replace the view you pull out with the "placeholder" view.